# c# Change DataGridView Row BackColor

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Table From Database That holds Some informations about users i want when the Value of The User `Cell[5]` is `"Connected"` to change the backcolor of that row :

here is my function :

```
        public void Initialize(DataGridView Dt)
        {

            foreach(DataGridViewRow Row in Dt.Rows)
            {
                if (Row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Connected")
                {

                    Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }

                else
                {
                    Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                }
            }

        }
```

Everything work perfect no exceptions where thrown but My row color didnt change in both cases

Please Note That i m using `MetroGridView` from `Metro Dll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle cell formatting event to achieve your goal.
Tried a sample code below. It is working.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
              if(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "C")
              {
                  if(e.Value != null)
                  {
                      String StringValue =(String)e.Value;
                      if (StringValue.IndexOf("C1") > -1)
                      {

                          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                      }
                  }

              }

        }
```

Mu guess is, even though you are doing it right, the cell formatting event which triggers at later part, is overriding your changes.